# Pandas installation inPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, installation

I'm trying to install Pandas module in Python 2.7.3, and it's giving the following error:

`error: command '"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2`

I have installed Visual C++, and yet it is showing an error. What should I do to ensure its proper installation?

Comment: MY advice would be to save yourself a ton of pain and install an environment that comes with the numpy/scipy/pandas stack bundled already such as [anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) or my personal choice [winpython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Compiling Python extensions is a little difficult on Windows. I suggest that you use the Pandas MS Windows installer for your Python version.

Comment: I did that. By MS Windows Installer. It gave several errors still, of missing modules like, pytz, openpyxl, jdcal. Now that I installed these, it gives a:

    TypeError: copy() got an unexpected keyword 'font'